# Linq-to-SQL concatenate two columns in where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table set up like so:

```
prefix | value
 ABC     1234
 ABC     5678
 DEF     1234
```

Is it possible to create a linq query where prefix and value are concatenated for comparison in the where clause? I've tried this, but it always returns an empty set:

```
selected =
            from i in dc.items
            where i.prefix + i.value == "ABC1234"
            select i;
```

Edit: the following T-SQL comes up with the correct results:

```
 WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM([prefix])) + LTRIM(RTRIM([value])) = 'ABC1234'
```

Edit2: The following, which combines most of the answers below, still does not work:

```
where (String.Concat(i.prefix.Trim(), i.value.Trim())) == "ABC1234"
```

Edit3: So I've got it working, but I have no clue why. I've accepted an answer but if someone posts why it works I'd be grateful :)

This works (returns n rows):

```
var temp = dc.items.Where(i => i.prefix.Trim() + i.prefix.Trim() == "ABC1234");
```

This does not work (returns 0 rows):

```
var temp =
            from i in dc.items
            where i.prefix.Trim() + i.value.Trim() == "ABC1234"
            select i;
```

Comment: I think that should work. Are there spaces in the values (so that the concatenation really == "ABC 1234")?

Comment: What are the data types of prefix and value, are the `varchar(n)` or `char(n)`? If they are `char(n)` they will contain padding spaces.

Comment: Doh they are char(n). I added .Trim() to both, that didn't help however.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the output of the bottom example?

Comment: Can you profile the last example and post or at least examine the SQL generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont's speak english. Try this:

```
var selected = dc.Where(x => x.prefix + x.value == "ABC1234");
```

Comment: I assume "selected" is a generic list

Comment: I assume "prefix" as string. If "value" is int then try this:
var selected = dc.Where(x => x.prefix + x.value.ToString() == "ABC1234")

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `value` is not a string, you could concatenate them like this:

```
var selected = dc.Items.Where(x => string.Concat(x.prefix, x.value) == "ABC1234");
```

The benefit to using `string.Concat` is that all of the arguments will be converted to string.

Comment: value is char(n), but I did try String.Concat before I asked, didn't help :-\

Comment: var selected = dc.Items.Where(x => string.Concat(x.prefix, x.value).Contains("ABC1234"));

this is other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
where (i.prefix + i.value) == "ABC1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select this

```
selected =
 from c in db.items

 select new {

 Name = string.Format("{0}{1}", c.prefix , c.value)

};
```

and look will you have "ABC1234"